# jQuery append to this

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to append something to `this` on a click function. Basically on click, I want to target something and append it to the element I clicked on. This is what I have so far.

```
jQuery(".pop-up-menu-left ul .menu-item-has-children").click(function(){
    jQuery("#sub-menu-container").find(".sub-menu").appendTo(this);
});
```

Here's the HTML before clicking:

```
<div class="pop-up-menu-left">
     <ul>
          <li><a>item</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>item</a></li>
          <li><a>item</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>

<div class="pop-up-menu-right">
     <div id="sub-menu-container">
          <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a>item</a></li>
              <li><a>item</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

And heres what I want the HTML to look like after clicking:

```
<div class="pop-up-menu-left">
     <ul>
          <li><a>item</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item-has-children">
             <a>item</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li>item</li>
                  <li>item</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a>item</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>

<div class="pop-up-menu-right">
     <div id="sub-menu-container">
          
     </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: would be great if you post a code snippet

Comment: @GTown-Coder ive updated my answer with the basic html layout

Comment: What if you click twice? :D :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan then the computer blows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is *what if one clicks more than once* - you clearly want to prevent that submenu being appended more than once:

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

  var $sub = $("#sub-menu-container").find(".sub-menu");

  $(".pop-up-menu-left .menu-item-has-children").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent browser default behavior
    
    if( ! $(this).has($sub).length ) { // Append only if missing
      $(this).append($sub);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
[class^=pop-up-menu]{margin:10px; background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<div class="pop-up-menu-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a>item</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>CLICK ME</a></li>
    <li><a>item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="pop-up-menu-right">
  <div id="sub-menu-container">
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a>item</a></li>
      <li><a>item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```